# Form is posted before buttn pressed

Tags: javascript

I've found on the net the below code to preview an image before it's uploaded. I'm good only with classic asp and when it comes to javascript I'm totally ignorant and need some help.
I have a simple asp page that contains a form, where I can select an image, preview it and then post the form to the filesave.asp page.
The problem is that as soon as I press the "Choose Image" button the page is posted before I can select the image. I think that the problem is with the "addEventListener" instruction but don't know how to solve it.
This is the div I have into the form:

```
<div id="preview-container">
<button id="upload-dialog">Choose Image</button>
<input type="file" id="image-file" name="image" accept="image/jpg,image/png" />
<img id="preview-image" />
<span id="image-name"></span>
<button id="upload-button">Upload</button>
<button id="cancel-image">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

And this is the script that handles the preview and doesn't give me the time to select the image:

```
<script>
  var _PREVIEW_URL;

  /* Show Select File dialog */
  document.querySelector("#upload-dialog").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector("#image-file").click();
  });

  /* Selected File has changed */
  document.querySelector("#image-file").addEventListener('change', function() {
  // user selected file
  var file = this.files[0];

  // allowed MIME types
  var mime_types = [ 'image/jpeg', 'image/png' ];

 // validate MIME
 if(mime_types.indexOf(file.type) == -1) {
    alert('Error : Incorrect file type');
    return;
  }

  // validate file size
  if(file.size > 2*1024*1024) {
    alert('Error : Exceeded size 2MB');
    return;
  }

  // validation is successful

  // hide upload dialog button
  document.querySelector("#upload-dialog").style.display = 'none';

  // set name of the file
  document.querySelector("#image-name").innerText = file.name;
  document.querySelector("#image-name").style.display = 'inline-block';

  // local url
  _PREVIEW_URL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  // set src of image and show
 document.querySelector("#preview-image").setAttribute('src', _PREVIEW_URL);
 document.querySelector("#preview-image").style.display = 'inline-block';

 // show cancel and upload buttons now
 document.querySelector("#cancel-image").style.display = 'inline-block';
 document.querySelector("#upload-button").style.display = 'inline-block';
 });

 /* Reset file input */
 document.querySelector("#cancel-image").addEventListener('click', function() {
 // destroy previous local url
 URL.revokeObjectURL(_PREVIEW_URL);

// show upload dialog button
 document.querySelector("#upload-dialog").style.display = 'inline-block';

// reset to no selection
 document.querySelector("#image-file").value = '';

// hide elements that are not required
 document.querySelector("#image-name").style.display = 'none';
 document.querySelector("#preview-image").style.display = 'none';
 document.querySelector("#cancel-image").style.display = 'none';
 document.querySelector("#upload-button").style.display = 'none';
 });

/* Upload file to server */
document.querySelector("#upload-button").addEventListener('click', function() {
// AJAX request to server
alert('This will upload file to server');
```

});

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing <button id="upload-dialog"> to <button id="upload-dialog" type="button">

Comment: Same problem. As soon as I select the image the form is posted while I'd need the previewed image to stay until upload button is pressed.

Answer (score -1):

Better test with the following javascript and html.

```js
var _PREVIEW_URL;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  /* Show Select File dialog */
  document.querySelector("#upload-dialog").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector("#image-file").click();
  });

  /* Selected File has changed */
  document.querySelector("#image-file").addEventListener('change', function() {
  // user selected file
  var file = this.files[0];

  // allowed MIME types
  var mime_types = [ 'image/jpeg', 'image/png' ];

 // validate MIME
 if(mime_types.indexOf(file.type) == -1) {
    alert('Error : Incorrect file type');
    return;
  }

  // validate file size
  if(file.size > 2*1024*1024) {
    alert('Error : Exceeded size 2MB');
    return;
  }

  // validation is successful

  // hide upload dialog button
  document.querySelector("#upload-dialog").style.display = 'none';

  // set name of the file
  document.querySelector("#image-name").innerText = file.name;
  document.querySelector("#image-name").style.display = 'inline-block';

  // local url
  _PREVIEW_URL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  // set src of image and show
 document.querySelector("#preview-image").setAttribute('src', _PREVIEW_URL);
 document.querySelector("#preview-image").style.display = 'inline-block';

 // show cancel and upload buttons now
 document.querySelector("#cancel-image").style.display = 'inline-block';
 document.querySelector("#upload-button").style.display = 'inline-block';
 });

 /* Reset file input */
 document.querySelector("#cancel-image").addEventListener('click', function() {
 // destroy previous local url
 URL.revokeObjectURL(_PREVIEW_URL);

// show upload dialog button
 document.querySelector("#upload-dialog").style.display = 'inline-block';

// reset to no selection
 document.querySelector("#image-file").value = '';

// hide elements that are not required
 document.querySelector("#image-name").style.display = 'none';
 document.querySelector("#preview-image").style.display = 'none';
 document.querySelector("#cancel-image").style.display = 'none';
 document.querySelector("#upload-button").style.display = 'none';
 });

/* Upload file to server */
document.querySelector("#upload-button").addEventListener('click', function() {
// AJAX request to server
alert('This will upload file to server');
});
});
```

```html
<div id="preview-container">
<button id="upload-dialog" type="button">Choose Image</button>
<input type="file" id="image-file" name="image" accept="image/jpg,image/png" />
<img id="preview-image" />
<span id="image-name"></span>
<button id="upload-button">Upload</button>
<button id="cancel-image">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Miller, thank you first of all, for helping me but i still have the problem. I meanif iput the html code in a form like this: container div then form, the code, then end form and and div, as soon as I select the image the form is submitted while I'd need to press the upload button and then the form is posted. unfortunately I'm a complete dummy with javascript.